# Mysql find date range

Tags: mysql

Given the following values YYYY-MM-DD

```
$start = 2012-03-21
$stop = 2012-07-15
```

and the following records in the DB, also YYYY-MM-DD

```
    DATE_FROM    DATE_TO       PRICE
    2012-01-01   2012-03-01    123
    2012-03-01   2012-04-08    123
    2012-04-09   2012-06-04    456
    2012-06-04   2012-07-02    789
    2012-07-02   2012-07-16    111
    2012-07-17   2012-08-17    222
```

How can I select all records that fall within the range of `$start` - `$stop`? This should include all except the last and first row

Attempt below, which gets records 2 - 4 but not 5.

```
    SELECT date_from, date_to, price 
    FROM periods
    WHERE (date(date_from) <= '$start' OR date(date_to) <= '$stop')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want logic something like this:

```
date_to >= $start AND date_from <= $stop
```

If this is what you are looking for:

```
Start-----Stop
       From-------------------To

           Start-----Stop
       From-------------------To

                      Start-----Stop
       From-------------------To
```

Notice that `Start` always has to come before `To` **AND** `Stop` always has to come after `From` for this overlap to occur.

Let me know if any of my assumptions are off of what you are looking for. But, either way, I always find something like this easier to write down so you can visualize and easily see the greater than/less than situations.

Comment: WHERE (date(date_to) >= '$start' AND date(date_from) >= '$stop') - returns nothing.

Comment: Updated my answer. I had your to/from backwards, and had a logic/typo flaw anyway. I double checked this in my head, and it should get you the rows 2-5

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date_from, date_to, price 
    FROM periods
    WHERE (date_from BETWEEN '$start' AND '$stop') AND (date_to BETWEEN '$start' AND '$stop')
```

Comment: This will not work (if my assumption is correct). See my answer for the reasoning.

Comment: oh I see, I did it the wrong way, parameters must be inside range from database dates. Good explanation